# Локальная функция для каждого div

Tags: jquery, ajax

Не пойму как заставить работать функцию внутри каждого DIV S1

```
<div class="s1">
    <div class="active">1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="s1">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="active">2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Мой код:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="s1">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="s1">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<script>
    var s1 = $('.s1 div');
    var s = $('.s1 div').val();
    s1.click(function (){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.s1 div').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s1 = $('.s1 div');
var s = $('.s1 div').text(); // div does not have value
s1.click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.s1').find('div').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
    // or
    $(this).siblings('div').removeClass('active');
});
```